# Filter Content on all Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, hooks, advanced-custom-fields, the-content

I had this idea to introduce a 'post type footer' using Advanced Custom Fields so that my users could set up common, reusable messages or calls to action and have them appear after the content of a specific post type. This works great on my native post types as I can simply filter the_content but doesn't work on post types that don't employ this hook, like WooCommerce 'products' for example.

Can anyone recommend a way in which I could hook into all post types via a single hook without editing templates?

I should mention as well that I'm attempting to make this applicable to post types that might be added later by the client, which is why I can't make changes to the post type templates directly. To this end also, my admin section gets the active post types of that particular environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All I can think is to process the posts at an earlier stage with a Core hook. This is crude, of course, but:

```
function hack_the_post($posts) {
  foreach ($posts as $p) {
    $p->post_content .= ' I added this';
  }
  return $posts;
}
add_action('the_posts', 'hack_the_post');
```

It is a bit energy intensive but so long as your plugin/theme uses more or less standard core functions it should work.